# Specific Subdomain point to a path and a dynamic subdomains point to another path

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I am developing an application where I have some specific subdomains, see:

1. www.120mmsm.com is the site - OK
2. signup.120mmsm.com is the registration page - ERROR
3. login.120mmsm.com is the login page - ERROR
4. anything.120mmsm.com is to fall in the system folder - OK

So the site is responding at www. The dynamic subdomain has managed to do. But the signup and login to fall into different folders can not. Give and you can see when you enter the urls above.

My htaccess code:

```
#does nothing if www
RewriteRule ^www/ - [L] 

#Force https for everything that is not www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www)\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#signup
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(signup)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ signup/$1 [L]

#login
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(login)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ login/$1 [L]

#system
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sistema/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.120mmsm.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|singup|login)?([a-z0-9-]+).120mmsm.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ sistema/$1
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I solved my problem doing this: 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www|login|signup).120mmsm.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).120mmsm.com [NC]

Answer (score 1):

What type of error did you get? Are you sure you have the right configuration of Apache?

Comment: Thanks @Timur,
I have an error Internal Server Error. To access the page you can see.
The Apache configuration for wildcard and others are ok. Both the site with www and the system responds well.

  The subdomain is for signup to fall into the signup folder does not work.

  Try acess https://signup.120mmsm.com

Comment: First of all, check you apache error log. There must be information about this error. Then, if there is nothing, try to replace "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|singup|login)?([a-z0-9-]+).120mmsm.com [NC]" with "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|singup|login)?([a-z0-9-]*).120mmsm.com [NC]"

Comment: Thanks @Timur, I solved my problem doing this:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www|login|signup).120mmsm.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).120mmsm.com [NC]